# How to generate pdf document using jspdf without changing alignment when application is loaded in mobile - Angular 8

Tags: angular, user-interface, responsive, jspdf, html2pdf

I am using jspdf library to generate the pdf document.The functionality works perfectly fine both in web view and mobile view(Mobile view i mean when the application is loaded in browser in mobile ). But I am facing issue with change of alignment in mobile view. I have two tables side by side when the pdf is generated in web view. But in mobile view, the table comes one below the other. Is there any way to generate the pdf without changing the position and alignment of fields and tables. Below is the code and I have attached both web view and mobile view pdf attachment. In simple words, I have all the fields and tables occupied in one page in web view. The same I would want to achieve in mobile view. (But in my case, pdf occupies two pages in mobile view, instead all fields and tables should be in one page same as web view pdf). The code for fields and tables is written in client side using html code in typescript file.

Comment: Is there no solution for this? Can we achieve this or its not supported.?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was basically the bootstrap class was not set for extra small devices, so the alignment was not coming properly when the pdf is downloaded. Added col- classes wherever required and it was fine.